# COUNT rows from multiple joined tables - MSSQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, count, left-join

I'm trying to make a simple forum for a school-project.
I'm having some troubles with my query.
I have 3 tables, that I'm trying to join. "Categories", "Threads" and "Post".

**ERD**

[image: ERD]

**The table data**

Category

[image: Category]

Threads

[image: Threads]

Posts

[image: Posts]

(Even though the name-spelling is a little bit different in the DB, the columns and tables are the same, as shown in the image.)
As soon as I join the second table ("Posts"), the result from the "Threads"-count is wrong.
If I only left join and count the rows in "Threads", then the result is right.

When i do this:

```
    SELECT Category.Name AS CategoryName, Category.Description AS
    CategoryDescription, COUNT(Threads.Id) AS NumberOfThreads
    FROM Category
    LEFT JOIN Threads ON Threads.FkCategoryId = Category.Id GROUP
    BY Category.Name, Category.Description
```

The Result is

[image]

Which returns the actual number of rows in "Threads". All is good so far,
BUT when i add the second join

```
    SELECT Category.Name AS CategoryName, Category.Description AS CategoryDescription,
    COUNT(Threads.Id) AS NumberOfThreads,
    COUNT(Posts.Id) AS NumberOfPosts
    FROM Category
    LEFT JOIN Threads ON Threads.FkCategoryId = Category.Id
    LEFT JOIN Posts ON Posts.FkThreadId = Threads.Id
    GROUP BY Category.Name, Category.Description
```

Then i get this result:

[image]

Which shows the actual number of rows in "Posts" as both "Threads" and "Posts".

I have also tried to combine multiple queries in one like this:

```
    SELECT Category.Name AS CategoryName, Category.[Description] AS
    CategoryDescription, COUNT(Threads.Id) AS NumberOfThreads
    FROM Category
    LEFT JOIN Threads ON Category.Id = Threads.FkCategoryId
    GROUP BY Category.Name, Category.Description;

    SELECT COUNT(Posts.Id) AS NumberOfPosts
    FROM Category
    LEFT JOIN Threads ON Category.Id = Threads.FkCategoryId
    LEFT JOIN Posts ON Threads.Id = Posts.FkThreadId
    GROUP BY Category.Id;
```

Which gives me this result:

[image]

which is the correct data. I would just rather combine it in 1 query, because I can't "Eval" "NumberOfPosts" form the second query.

I get this Error:

> "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property
>   with the name 'NumberOfPosts'"

I have read and tried a lot of different things, and don't know how to solve it. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
SELECT CatThread.CategoryName, CatThread.CategoryDescription,
    CatThread.NumberOfThreads,
    COUNT(Posts.Id) AS NumberOfPosts
FROM 
   ( select Category.Id, Category.Name AS CategoryName, Category.Description AS CategoryDescription,
    COUNT(Threads.Id) AS NumberOfThreads
    from Category
      LEFT JOIN Threads ON Threads.FkCategoryId = Category.Id
    group by  Category.Id, Category.Name, Category.Description) CatThread
    LEFT JOIN Threads ON Threads.FkCategoryId = CatThread.Id
    LEFT JOIN Posts ON Posts.FkThreadId = Threads.Id
GROUP BY CatThread.CategoryName, CatThread.CategoryDescription,
    CatThread.NumberOfThreads
```

I did not create the tables and such to make sure this works, but I believe this query should give you what you want. You might have to tweak the syntax and such. The basic idea is to use a sub-query to get the Threads per Category row counts in a single row, which then can be joined to the Posts table.

Comment: I edited the query. Dimt is correct, I was missing joins in the main query. The sub-query needs to be joined through the Threads table.

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. Now i just have to study the code to understand what happens, as i havent really played with subqueries before :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missed join condition `Post.FkUserId = Threads.FkUserId` on the second join.

Try:

```
 LEFT JOIN Posts ON Threads.Id = Posts.FkThreadId  AND PostFkUserId = Threads.FkUserId
```

Basically you query matches more records because you join only on the `Threads.Id = Posts.FkThreadId`. In the **Post** table there is 7 records with FkThreadId that is 7,6,6,5,2,2,2.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. That's what I get for not creating the tables and really trying it.

Comment: Your answer was also very helpful. Thank you.